# Non-breaking characters in WinForms labels?

Tags: winforms, formatting, label

In WinForms, is there a way to add a non-breaking hyphen to a `System.Windows.Forms.Label` control?

e.g. Don't break like this:

```
======================
|  VB is SO un-      |
|  cooperative!      |
======================
```

Instead break like this!

```
======================
|  VB is SO          |
|  un-cooperative!   |
======================
```

Comment: Using the designer? or in code?

Comment: have u placed space after or before '-'? check my post i could not reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Forms Designer you could select the Label's Text property. Click on the dropdown arrow on the far right and type your text. You could break it at the desidered position by pressing SHIFT+ENTER.

In code it is simply

```
label1.Text = "VB is SO\nun-cooperative!";
```

or in VB.NET

```
label1.Text = "VB is SO" & Environemnt.NewLine & "un-cooperative!"
```

Comment: I suppose that's possible in this case, though it wouldn't help if the label & form were resizable...

Answer (score 0):

Check this, its working properly

[image]

text does not break after or before '-'. i have tested in my testing project and its working properly. even i reduce the width of label it get cut from the right side as displayed in my screenshot.

still getting problem then you have another option is that create custom user control for label and write some code for word wrap there are lot of code exist on internet for wordwrap process. available in VB.net also. btw windows form does not allow any event or override method that you can handle it for wrap text.